# Извлечь числа из строки python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Коллеги! Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, начинаю осваивать питон, имею следующую строку с данными:

```
"SMART
DEVICE
SN: 242100000004
IMEI: 866795000009306
MyTelecom, LLC
Russia
EAC 4.0
PIN
PUK
SIM-карта
с поддержкой
4G LTE
0000
41750006
Контактный центр МТС
(в сети МТС бесплатно)
0890 )
Проверка баланса
*100#)
Пополнение баланса
без комиссии
oplata.mts.ru
Контроль расходов,
смена тарифа
+111# приложение
«Мой МТС»
8970101783283000000-9
HLR: 328
SIMTrio M2M
www.mts.ru"
```

Как из этой строки, я могу получить значения:

- IMEI (всегда содержит 15 цифр);
- Номер сим-карты (всегда содержит 20
  цифр и дефис: 8970101783283000000-9)

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант:

```
import re
s = "..."
imei = re.search(r'\d{15}', s).group(0)
sim = re.search(r'\d{19}-\d', s).group(0)
print(imei)
print(sim)
```

https://ideone.com/YOsoMk